# background hover not appearing behind title

Tags: html, css

The problem I have with my coding is I would like the image title to stay fixed on and off mouse over but the colored background only appears underneath the title and not behind the title. If i could get the background to go all the way behind the title instead of just underneath the title on mouseover. I have attached a few pics of what the current issue is as well is what I would like the solution to be. I have also attached some sample coding of  HTML and CSS so you can see the code as well. Thank you!

```css
.section{
 margin-top: -70px;
 margin-right: 225px;
 margin-left: 217px;
}
/*Portfolio Gallery*/
.view {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  border: 10px solid #909090;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("../images/over1.jpg");
  border-radius: 50%;
   -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #000000;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
   box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #000000;
  max-width: 30.26%;
 height: 300px;
}

.view .mask,
.view .content {
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0
}

.view h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: underline;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  background:#000000;
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.view p {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
  font-family: Merriweather, serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow:
  -1px -1px 0 #000,
  1px -1px 0 #000,
  -1px 1px 0 #000,
  1px 1px 0 #000;

}

.view a.info {
  font-size: 26px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Raleway, serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}

.view a.info:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000
}


/*1*/

.view-first img {
  /*1*/
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.view-first .mask  {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 opacity: 0;
 background-color: rgba(255,0,4,0.57);
 transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 height: 100%; 
 
}

.view-first h2 {
  transform: translateY(1px);
  opacity: 100;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.view-first p {
  transform: translateY(100px);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.view-first a.info {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}


/* */

.view-first:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.view-first:hover .mask {
 display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}

.view-first:hover h2,
.view-first:hover p,
.view-first:hover a.info {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.view-first:hover p {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.view-first:hover a.info {
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="section group">
 <div class="view view-first">
 <h2>LOGOS</h2>
 <div class="mask">
      <p>The Beginning Part Of The Branding Process.Logos I Have Done For Clients</p>
      <a href="#" class="info">Click Here</a>
    </div>
 </div>
```

#### Regular View:

[image: Image on Regular view]

#### Issue:

[image: THE ISSUE]

#### Desired Result:

[image: The desired result]

Comment: I do believe the attached sample code is a bit wrong when compared to the pictures provided... Could you fix it, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is  the class **.view-first .mask**.

For the expected result the class mentioned needs POSITION: ABSOLUTE and not RELATIVE.

```
.view-first .mask  {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 opacity: 0;
 background-color: rgba(255,0,4,0.57);
 transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 height: 100%; 
}
```

Doing so will achieve the expected result, but another problem will appear. You will need to adjust the margin-top of the following classes:

**.view-first p**

**.view a.info**

Answer (score 0):

```css
.view-first .mask  {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  /* background-color: rgba(255,0,4,0.57); */
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  height: 100%; 
}

.view.view-first {
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.view.view-first:hover {
  background: rgba(255,0,4,0.57);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

Remove `background-color: rgba(255,0,4,0.57);` from `.view-first .mask` div and give it to the parent div so the whole div will get the color